# NPCs not moving in in Terraria iOS, despite all room conditions being met

Tags: ios, terraria-mobile

Now I have been on plenty of websites but none seem to answer my problem, my NPCs won't move in, I have my layout identical each side but the right side of my house the NPCs won't movie in... I've checked that it's not day, the NPC is requesting to settle down, I am not being invaded so what is it?[image: The house (multiple pictures combined to fit the full house in)]

Comment: @Frank If you'd look at the screenshot it clearly shows valid housing, with NPCs that have already been assigned to each room, so OP obviously knows how to build a house for NPCs. He just wants to know where they are, so this is NOT a duplicate.

Comment: @contrabandbandicoot The screenshot does not show the *other* requirements, such as not being close to corruption.  It still most definitely is a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

If they won't move in on one side of the house, and it is identical-on the interior-to a side they will move in on then the answer is almost certainly that the [corruption](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Corruption)(or crimson) is [too close](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/House#Location) to that side of the house. This can be fixed by removing corrupted tiles, or by moving the house further away.

Or I suppose you could plant a whole bunch (potentially hundreds) of sunflowers next to the house.